# How to Sum Date (in minutes) Shell

Tags: shell, shell-script, date-time

I need some help here, I'm not a expert with shell scripting but I am trying to do a script where I need to take the Epoch number followed by the date, but for with the all hours of the day with a interval of 15 minutes. The result will be something like this

```
1376708400|2013-08-17 00:00:00
1376709300|2013-08-17 00:15:00
1376710200|2013-08-17 00:30:00
```

In the total I'll have 96 lines, my biggest doubt right now is how i can increment (or sum) the minutes by 15 minutes, i have tried this

My full script right now is this (I know is terrible, but I'm not a truly programmer. I'm learning)

```
i=96

_incrementatime='+15 minutos'

count=1

_Date=$(`date "2013-08-29 00:00:00"`)
_dataEmSeg = `date -d "2013-08-29 00:00:00" +%s`

while  test $i -ne 0

do
    _VarData=$(`date --date="$_incrementatime*count"`)

    _exprt=$(expr `$_Date+$_VarData`)
    echo "$_dataEmSeg  e  $_exprt    "

    i=$((i-1))
    count=$((count+1))
done
```

If someone can give me the directions to resolve this I`ll be very thankfull.

Comment: Is this bash or another shell? Looks like bash but you have not said. I also assume you are running some kind of *nix system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU `date`, it can almost do everything itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_Date=$(date -d "2013-08-29 00:00:00");
for ((i=0; i<96; i++)); do 
    echo $(date -d "$_Date" +%s)"|"$(date -d "$_Date" +"%F %T")
    _Date=$(date -d "$_Date +15 minutes")
done
```

There were various small errors and unnecessary steps in your script which I removed or corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the system you're on, but there's `dseq(1)` from my [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) collection to produce a sequence of dates:

```
$ dseq '2013-08-17 00:00:00' +15m '2013-08-18 00:00:00' -f '%s|%F %T'
1376697600|2013-08-17 00:00:00
1376698500|2013-08-17 00:15:00
...
```

The first 3 arguments denote the starting and end point of the sequence, the middle one being the increment (just like `seq(1)` really).  The `-f` switch allows you to specify the output format, and takes format specifiers similar to those in GNU `date`.